# training a kNN algorithm with different features for each record

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, knn

I have a dataset where each record could contain a different number of features.
The features in total are 56, and each record can contain from 1 to 56 record of this features.

Each features is like a flag, so or exist in the dataset or not, and if it exist, there is another value, double, that put the value of it.

An example of dataset is this
[image]

I would know if is possibile training my kNN algorithm using different features for each record, so for example one record has 3 features plus label, other one has 4 features plus label, etc...

I am trying to implement this in Python, but I have no idea about how I have to do.

Comment: why do you need to use kNN? there are other algorithms that can deal with missing values

Comment: Because I need to know which is the record more near of one take in input and which label it belongs

Comment: So you are doing a 1- NN. If you explain more of your problem we can give you better indications....what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Is not a 1NN because I have to classify it, and with 1NN is not possibile to classify.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is definitely possible. The one thing you need to think about is the distance measure.

The default distance used for kNN Classifiers is usually Euclidean distance. However,Euclidean distance requires records (vectors) of equal number of features (dimensions).

The distance measure you use, highly depends on what you think should make records similar.

If you have a correspondence between features of two records, so you know that feature i of record x describes the same feature as feature i from record y you can adapt Euclidean distance. For example you could either ignore missing dimensions (such that they don't add to the distance if a feature is missing in one record) or penalize missing dimensions (such that a certain penalty value is added whenever a feature is missing in a record).

If you do not have a correspondence between the features of two records, then you would have to look at set distances, e.g., minimum matching distance or Hausdorff distance.

Answer (score 0):

Every instance in your dataset should be represented by the same number of features. If you have data with a variable number of features (e.g. each data point is a vector of x and y where each instance has different number of points) then you should treat such points as missing values.

Therefore you need to deal with missing values. For example:

1. Replace missing values with the mean value for each column.
2. Select an algorithm that is able to handle missing values such as Decision trees.
3. Use a model that is able to predict missing values.

**EDIT**

First of all you need to bring the data into a better format. Currently, each feature is represented by two columns which is not a very nice technique. Therefore I would suggest to restructure the data as follows:

```
+------+------------+-----------+----------+--------+
| ID   |  Feature1  |  Feature2 | Feature3 | Label  |
+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------+
|  1   |    15.12   |   ?       |   56.65  |  True  |
|  2   |    ?       |   23.6    |   ?      |  True  |
|  3   |    ?       |   12.3    |   ?      |  False |
+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

Then you can either replace missing values (denoted with `?`) with `0` (this depends on the "meaning" of each feature) or use one of the techniques that I've already mentioned before.

Comment: Each feature is like a flag, so or the feature exist or not. So I can not predict the values.
About the Decision tree it can be a good alternative, thanks!

Comment: Then you have boolean features. You should NOT ignore features that are equal to `False` (or `0`) nor to consider them as missing.

Comment: Exactly, indeed an idea is to use all the features and not part of them

Comment: In your question you mentioned that you have instances with different number of features which essentially is not true. You have instances with the same number of features but with different values for each of the features which is quite normal. Could you please edit your initial post and provide some of the instances in your dataset?

Comment: I've updated it, I'm so sorry for my bad description of the problem!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163421/discussion-between-protti-and-giorgos-myrianthous).